# why i am getting segmentation fault only when run my code in codechef?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

This here is the code. The code works fine when i run it in `VS Code 2019` and other online compilers as well! **But** when run it in Codechef [here](https://www.codechef.com/ide/?itm_medium=navmenu&itm_campaign=ide) i get some runtime segmentation fault error.

**The code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while (T >= 1 && T <= 100)
    {
        char a[10] ;
        int x_counter = 0, y_counter = 0;
        scanf("%s", &a);
        char* ptr = a;
        while (*ptr != '\0')
        {
            if (*ptr == 'x')
                x_counter++;
            else if (*ptr == 'y')
                y_counter++;
            ptr++;
        }
        if (x_counter < y_counter)
        {
            printf("%d\n", x_counter);
        }
        else if (y_counter <= x_counter)
        {
            printf("%d\n", y_counter);
        }
        T--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do `a` have enough elements? Also you are invoking *undefined behavior* by passing `printf()` data having wrong type: `char*` is expected for `%s` but `char(*)[10]` is passed. The `&` before `a` in `scanf()` should be removed.

Comment: `else if (y_counter <= x_counter)` can be just `else` and in fact all that `if ... else ...` can be simplified to `printf("%d\n", (x_counter < y_counter) ? x_counter : y_counter);` . Initialize *T* (wrongly named in uppercase) with a value out of the valid range like 0 or check `scanf("%d", &T)` returns 1 to manage wrong input. Replace `scanf("%s", &a);` by `scanf("%9s", a);` because *a* is sized 10 and you also need place for the final null char, and again check `scanf` returns 1 to detect error like EOF or before the `scanf` do `*a=0;`

Comment: I tried removing & from scanf() and increased the number of elements to 1000. But same error is shown again.:(

Comment: Then how about 7000000 elements? Don't the problem say about the maximum input size?

Comment: the modified 'm' is very useful to ask `scanf` to allocate by itself the right buffer size

Comment: You do not need **any buffer at all**, just read one character at a time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you program will run into undefined behavior [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20undefined%20behavior,which%20the%20computer%20code%20adheres.&text=In%20the%20C%20community%2C%20undefined,demons%22%2C%20after%20a%20comp.) cos you conversion specifier in the scanf `"%s"` expects a `char*` but you are passing array of char pointers (`char**` or `char(*)[]`).hence the pointer arguments for `scanf` must be of a type that is appropriate for the value returned by the corresponding conversion specification!! I recommend you to limit the `scanf` function and flush the `stdin` buffer in each iteration see below:

```
int c;
scanf("%9s", a);
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF); /* Flush stdin */
```

since `scanf` return `EOF` if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. `EOF` is also returned if a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set, and errno is set to indicate the error. `errno` is an integer variable definded in `<errno.h>` header, which is set by system calls and some library functions in the event of an error to indicate what went wrongwe can add the layer below:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
....
if(scanf("%9s", a) == EOF)
{
    puts(strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

```
char *strerror(int errnum);
```

> The `strerror()` function returns a pointer to a string that describes
> the error code passed in the argument errnum

for further details regarding `strerror` and `errno`. go to the links below:
[errno](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)
[strerror](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html)

Comment: `scanf()` will automatically put terminating null-character, even when length limit is hit. [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QP0fCG0QsmEspIvS).

Comment: `c` must be an `int`. Also `&a` would be of type `char (*)[10]` and *would* work correctly in most cases in scanf, so this cannot be quite the reason.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala -  the pointer arguments for scanf must be of a type that is appropriate for the value returned by the corresponding conversion specification.

Comment: @Adam yes, otherwise behaviour is undefined, however it practically never causes issues in this case because the representation of the value should be the same.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - thank you for your comments. your comments helped me to improve my  answer. but regarding scanf , we are trying to code right and folow the c standard. so relaying on some practical thing isnot something we can recommend some programmer to do. i would be glad if you voteit up :-)

Comment: Btw, better to use the `perror` instead of `puts(strerror)` ;)